# Problem with my CPU

Tags: cpu, process

I wanted to ask if this is normal:

Cpu(s):  6.3%us,  0.9%sy,  0.0%ni, 92.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st

I typed "top" and got this result, I realise that only 1-2 cores are really working...

And my laptop gets hot of course...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, but it was related with the discrete nvidia video card: it was always on, which was warming the whole system. Did you check that issue?

Correct me if I'm wrong, but that 6% of processor use, can be due to the wrong use of your video card settings

If you have an nvidia card, you can check the documentation of the 'bumblebee' project here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

For other cards, check this link: http://linux-hybrid-graphics.blogspot.com/

Hope it helps!